# Compare user input against collection (array of objects) - Command-line Node JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, prompt

I have some data stored in a collection (array of objects) and I am using **prompt on nodejs** to get information from the user which compares this data entry to the array of objects and **logs a string if true** and **logs an error if not true**

I need assistance with the else {} part, how do I go about doing this? Remember that the input will ask for the cardNo and PIN, and then compare both these values against a user to return something true or false.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var prompt = require('prompt');
prompt.start(); // Lets you prompt the user for info

// Dummy Users
var users = [{
    name: 'Zayn',
    cardNo: 4317307597302131,
    PIN: 1212
}, {
    name: 'Me',
    cardNo: 4929715360098035,
    PIN: 1213
}, {
    name: 'You',
    cardNo: 4539890581557184,
    PIN: 1313
}, {
    name: 'See',
    cardNo: 4205877325217426,
    PIN: 1314
}, {
    name: 'Who',
    cardNo: 4405488141962985,
    PIN: 1414
}, {
    name: 'Lol',
    cardNo: 4556666088651201,
    PIN: 1415
}];

// Prompt (which is Async) works like this:
prompt.get(['cardNo', 'PIN'], function (err, result) {

    if (err) { // Handle error
        return err;
    }
    else{
        for(var i=0; i < users.length; i++){
           if(users[i].cardNo === result.cardNo && users[i].PIN === result.PIN){
               console.log("valid user");
               //your logic on validation

               break;// use break or return something to stop looping after validation
           }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: now resolved - prompt.get asks for values by the user and saves them as strings, the array collection cannot compare against this since the object is defined with a number type.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over your users array and look for an object with bookID and PIN properties matching with that of result object in prompt.

```
if (err) { 
   console.log(err);
   // Handle error
}
else{
    for(var i=0; i < users.length; i++){
       if(users[i].bookID === result.bookID && users[i].PIN === result.PIN){
           console.log("valid user");
           //your logic on validation

           break;// use break or return something to stop looping after validation
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, i had something like this before - but it logs nothing?

Comment: Hi @Zayn, please try this or update your code which you tried if this doesn't work

Comment: Hi, still logs nothing - even if the entry is not correct..

It does this:

prompt: bookID: 123
prompt: PIN:  1212
// then logs nothing

Comment: I don't know how you are handling the error. Can you check for the correct entry?

Comment: I updated the code above to the full version, please check now and see for yourself.

Comment: you have a error here `users[i].s === result.PIN`. Correct it to `users[i].PIN === result.PIN`. Also try logging the error instead of returning it.

Comment: Hi, still no luck Rohit

Answer (score 0):

```
 console.log(
  users.find( user => 
   user.name === result.name &&
   user.PIN === result.PIN
  )
   ?true
   :new Error("not found")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`.some()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** to test over the users in the array. If it returns a truthy value then the user is valid otherwise it's not.

This is how should be your code:

```
prompt.get(['cardNo', 'PIN'], function(err, result) {
  if (err) { // Handle error
    return err;
  } else {
    if (users.some(function(u) {
        return u.PIN === result.PIN && u.cardNo === result.cardNo;
      })){
      console.log("valid user");
    } else {
      console.log("invalid user");
    }
  }
});
```

**Demo:**

This is a working Demo:

```js
var users = [{
  name: 'Zayn',
  cardNo: 4317307597302131,
  PIN: 1212
}, {
  name: 'Me',
  cardNo: 4929715360098035,
  PIN: 1213
}, {
  name: 'You',
  cardNo: 4539890581557184,
  PIN: 1313
}, {
  name: 'See',
  cardNo: 4205877325217426,
  PIN: 1314
}, {
  name: 'Who',
  cardNo: 4405488141962985,
  PIN: 1414
}, {
  name: 'Lol',
  cardNo: 4556666088651201,
  PIN: 1415
}];

result = {
  cardNo: 4405488141962985,
  PIN: 1414
};

if (users.some(function(u) {
    return u.PIN === result.PIN && u.cardNo === result.cardNo;
  })) {
  console.log("valid user");
} else {
  console.log("invalid user");
}
```

Comment: Hi, i've tried this - looks like a promising solution but it's outputting invalid user still?

Comment: @Zayn You just need to make sure your input is valid, please check the Demo in my answer, it works perfectly.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work for me. Still says invalid user with the error log: invalid user null